# Custom Listview shows nothing with AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm using code to load photo list from gallery into custom horisontal listview. Listview scrolls not smoothly. I decide to put loading photo in to background. But now listview shows nothing. Could you please give me any help? After some discussion i've made some correction. But the result shows empty listview.

Main.java

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
private HorizontalImageAdapter horizontalimageAdapter;
 private HorizontalListView listview;
 private Utilf utils;
 private ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_list_view);

         utils = new Utilf(this);
         imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();
         listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
         horizontalimageAdapter = new HorizontalImageAdapter(this, imagePaths);
         listview.setAdapter(horizontalimageAdapter);
     }
    }
```

HorizontalImageAdapter.java

```
public class HorizontalImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Activity context;
 private static ImageView imageView;
 private ArrayList<String> plotsImages;
 private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

 public HorizontalImageAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> plotsImages) {
  this.context = context;
  this.plotsImages = plotsImages;
  l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return plotsImages.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  if (holder.imageView != null) {
      new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(plotsImages.get(position));
  }

  return convertView;

 }

 private static class ViewHolder {
  ImageView imageView;
 }
}
```

ImageDownloader.java

```
 class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
            private int imageWidth = 96;

            public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
                imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(params[0]);
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {

                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } else {
//                      imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_placeholder));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your `loadBitmap(....)` method

Comment: set adapter in `onPostExecute`

Comment: this line `listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);` must be in `onPostExecute`

Comment: No offence but why are you trying to reinvent wheel ? Libraries like UIL (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and Picasso (https://github.com/square/picasso) are created to help you with exactly what your doing.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ, I think he already set adapter into listview. Async is for loading image into viewholder inside adapter. That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to use some horisontal scrolling through gallery showing thumbnails. So I've to do a custom adapter using some library or use widget HorizontalScrollView. What way have I to choose?

Answer (score 0):

- List item

  Please check your `getItem(int position)` method. It is returning null. Instead you have to return the Object from the list for that position itself
- getView() method

You are directly returning convertView. Instead take it in one separate variable like this code

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
      // configure view holder
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
          .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);
    if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
        || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
```

code taken from [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) link

Comment: This doesn't help. My code works well without async loading exepting smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because your imageview will be reused multiple times.
You need a way to check that once the asynctask is done loading the bitmap you're still are on the exact same row of the listview otherwise you will display images at random position while scrolling through the listview. To do so you can store the bitmap url as tag on the imageview and check that tag just before calling setImageBitmap(). If it matches you can display the bitmap, otherwise do nothing.

But like @HERO said why don't you use Picasso lib that will do this in an infinitly better way  ;)

Comment: I need horisontal listview.

Comment: Then you need to use a ViewPager and not a listview. But your code to load an image from an asynctask will only work randomly if you're displaying into the correct imageview (cf my answer)

Comment: ViewPager is not applicable for me as i need widget like gallery. Imageview is not null so it call async loading.

Comment: Am I need to reload adapter? But how to make that?

Comment: Yes but if the user is scrolling, chances are the imageview has been recycled you will not display the image where you want to. ViewPager IS what you need if you want to implement a gallery. I don't get your question about reloading the adapter. Please read my answer, which explain the problem you will face with your code